# FFMPEG Customized Quantization

Tags: ffmpeg

Can i use customised quantization table in FFMPEG. Is there any available option? If there is no option then where i can edit in the code. For e.g. while compressing JPEG custom quatization table can be give as a parameter

Comment: Which encoder ?

Comment: i am using H.264. I prefer to use libx265 for compression

Answer (score 2):

For libx265, custom quantization lists can be specified using `-x265-params scaling-list='filename'` where file has to be "in the HM format" . See http://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/cli.html#cmdoption-scaling-list

For libx264, it's `-x264opts cqmfile='filename'` where file is "a JM-compatible file"

Comment: Thanks... for the info. This is very helpful. I tried to search on the HM format. But could not get anything. I have following queries (a) I understand how to write a qtable for JPEG. (8*8) How to write HM file? Is there any template or sample file which you can share (b) Which source file contains the quantization table used by libx265 (c) I see there is an option for qpfile. Does this means i can give quantization table for each iFrame. Is there an option or i needs to edit source code. I want to ensure that SSIM for each iFrame is 0.98

Comment: I am trying to use the file with the following data. Keep getting "can;t read matrix..."

Comment: 10 20 29 40 49 59 69 78 
20 30 39 49 59 69 78 89 
30 39 49 59 69 79 88 98 
40 49 59 69 79 89 98 108 
49 59 68 78 88 98 108 118 
59 69 78 88 98 108 118 128 
69 79 88 98 108 118 128 138 
78 89 99 108 118 128 138 147 

7 13 20 26 32 39 45 52 
13 19 26 33 39 46 52 59 
20 26 32 39 45 52 59 65 
26 32 39 46 52 59 65 71 
33 39 46 52 59 65 71 77 
39 46 52 59 65 71 78 85 
45 52 58 65 71 78 84 91 
52 59 65 71 78 84 91 97                                                                                                   There will be six similar blocks